# Can I write behavioural unit tests using "Given-When-Then" in Pytest (Python)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, acceptance-testing

We currently have many unit tests in Python and we're using Pytest. Ideally I'd like to stay with Pytest as that's what the company has elected to be their testing framework of choice. I wonder if people recommend fixtures in Pytest or some other good way to do this.

When doing a quick Google I see people using docstrings to explain their scenarios.

```py
def test_all(self):
    """
    GIVEN a PhoneBook with a records property
    WHEN the all method is called
    THEN all numbers should be returned in ascending order
    """
```

I wonder if someone has more experience / real world examples in this area and can guide me a bit. In my previous company we wrote methods in C# a rough example being:

```
authedUser = givenAnAuthenticatedUser()
transactionResult = whenIReconcileATransaction(user, transaction)
result = thenTransactionStatusIsReconciled(transactionResult)

assert result == True
```

Cheers

Comment: `given, when, then` is the common syntax for behavior driven development. I haven't personally used it but you might want to look to see if this plugin satisfies your needs -- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd

Comment: wow, who would've thought I'd need to Google the acronym BDD... that looks perfect thanks heaps for this! oh cool it's based on Gherkin which I've used a few years ago so looks familiar.